# Blue Screen of Death when accessing a mapped network drive

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, network-drive

I'm facing a hard time solving a BSOD which happens whenever I access a mapped network drive.  It only happens when I access a particular folder in this drive.

The error code is:

```
BAD_POOL_HEADER
STOP : 0x00000019(0x00000020, 0x88EE2E28, 0x88EE2ED8, 0x0A160001)
```

Is there any way to fix this besides formatting my hard drive?  I have tried updating my drivers and performing a registry clean but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, try booting your computer in to "safe mode with networking", if you don't get it, it was down to third party software/drivers which you will have to examine/uninstall.

If you still get it, I would say this is most likely a network driver. You said you have updated them, I would say this is also bad and to try another version, or an alternate card. It could also be actual hardware damage to the network controller.

Comment: thx for the reply and sorry for my negligence. I have actually tried safe mode with networking. It does not cause me BSOD. So, do you mean i cause by software and driver??

i am just curious why other mapped network drive AND the other folder in the same mapped network drive does not cause BSOD, just the particular folder cause it and only the particular access the particular folder only cause BSOD. weird that i can say.

Comment: If you had no BSOD in safe mode, it is possible you have a program (could be anything) that is causing the issue, typical culprits are Anti Virus, Virtualisation or similar type tools. If it is just one folder, it could be that you have a corrupt/bad/virus(?) program which is loading when viewing the folder... but it is really hard to help remotely. Also, try looking in the event viewer (or using Bluescreen View http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html ) to see if there is more information.

Comment: *hard to explain, when I say viewing the folder, I mean, some programs will try to generate thumbnails or similar from content and it is possible that either the program generating the thumbnails have errors, or, the actual file is causing an error when being processed.

Comment: Thank a lot!!! a great help from you as I solve my problem with BlueScreen View. With its help, i found that there is really an Anti-Spyware program causing BSOD as last week the PC is attacked by spyware and need the XX Anti-spyware. But after i installed it, no problem. I think BSOD happen after it expired the trial version. Anyway really thank you for helping me.